# How can I fix invalid JSON content with a regular expression in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, regex

This is what I've tried:

```
// Input
let input = "{id: 1, name: apple, qty: 2, colors: [{id: 1, hex: #f95}], store: {id: 1, name: Apple Store}}"

let result = input.replace((/([\w]+)(:)/g), "\"$1\"$2");
// {"id": 1, "name": apple, "qty": 2, "colors": [{"id": 1, "hex": #f95}], "store": {"id": 1, "name": Apple Store}}
```

And then I just replace it like, `replaceAll(': ', ': "')`. I think it's not good practice to resolve it. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Instead of fixing the `input`. Check how to generate a valid JSON string

Comment: Also see [What is an XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/320245)  "asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem."

Comment: If you can control the data source, you should fix it to pass correct format. Otherwise, RegExp is not a tool to parse JS objects, I'd recommend you to load a library.

Comment: I keep coming across this post while searching for how to fix JSON. If you just need a one off thing, you can use an online tool like https://ray.run/tools/json-repairer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this way and it works:

```js
    class FixJson {
        constructor() {
            this.run = (json) => {
                const fixDataType = (json) => {
                    for (const key in json) {
                        if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            const value = json[key];
                            if (typeof value === 'object') {
                                fixDataType(value);
                            } else if (value === 'true' || value === 'false') {
                                json[key] = value === 'true';
                            } else if (!isNaN(value)) {
                                json[key] = Number(value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return json;
                }

                // Use the replace function to add double quotes around the property names
                const fixedJson = json.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+)/g, '"$1"');

                // Use the JSON.parse function to parse the fixed JSON string into a JavaScript object
                const obj = JSON.parse(fixedJson.replaceAll('" "', ' '));

                // Fix JSON data type, and return the result
                return fixDataType(obj)
            }
        }
    }

    const fix = new FixJson()
    let result = fix.run("<your_invalid_json>")
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried your solution and got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Expected ',' or '}' after property value in JSON at position 118` with your stated input

Comment: @PeterThoeny I update my code, `const obj = JSON.parse(fixedJson.replaceAll('" "', ' '))`. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the stated string that looks almost like an object into an actual JavaScript object with the following assumptions:

- keys are composed of alphanumeric and underscores characters
- values are treated as numbers if they have the format of a number, e.g., an optional minus sign, followed by digits with optional `.`
- values are treated as a string unless it has the form of a number, or start with `[` (array) or `{` (object)
- string values may not contain `,` or `}`

```js
const input = "{id: 1, name: apple, qty: 2, colors: [{id: 1, hex: #f95}], store: {id: 1, name: Apple Store}}";
const regex1 = /([,\{] *)(\w+):/g;
const regex2 = /([,\{] *"\w+":)(?! *-?[0-9\.]+[,\}])(?! *[\{\[])( *)([^,\}]*)/g;
let json = input
  .replace(regex1, '$1"$2":')
  .replace(regex2, '$1$2"$3"')
let result = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, ' '));
```

Output:

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "apple",
 "qty": 2,
 "colors": [
  {
   "id": 1,
   "hex": "#f95"
  }
 ],
 "store": {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Apple Store"
 }
}
```

Explanation of regex1:

- `([,\{] *)` -- capture group 1: `,` or `{`, followed by optional spaces
- `(\w+)` -- capture group 2: 1+ word characters (alphanumeric and underscore)
- `:` -- literal `:`
- replace `'$1"$2":'` -- capture group 1, followed by capture group 2 enclosed in quotes, followed by colon

Explanation of regex2:

- `([,\{] *"\w+":)` -- capture group 1: `,` or `{`, followed by optional spaces, quote, 1+ word characters, quote, colon
- `(?! *-?[0-9\.]+[,\}])` -- negative lookahead for optional spaces, a number, followed by `,` or `}`
- `(?! *[\{\[])` -- negative lookahead for optional spaces, followed by `{` or `[`
- `( *)` -- capture group 2: optional spaces
- `([^,\}]*)` -- capture group 3: everything that is not a `,` or `}`
- replace `'$1$2"$3"'` -- capture group 1, followed by capture group 2, followed by capture group 3 enclosed in quotes

Learn more about regex: *[Presentation: Regular Expressions, To Match Or Not, That is the Question, Silicon Valley Code Camp, 2018-10-14](https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex)*